Can I use 1 docking station for 2 different laptops?
I have two laptops:
HP EliteBook (for work)
Dell G16 (personal)
I have been trying to find a docking station that can be used for both laptops.
I thought I should ask before purchasing any docking station:
Can I connect both laptops to the docking station for power?
Is there any specific setting or information I should be looking for to ensure the docking station can power both laptops?



While USB Power Delivery is a standard, most laptop makers have proprietary extensions. What power do the respective power supplies provide?

Oh yeah, also: Just because both have Thunderbolt ports does not necessarily mean they accept power input on that port.
